# Add function definition in llvm IR

Tags: llvm

I'd like to insert following function definition to `llvm IR`

```
 define internal void @main.new.fn(i8* nocapture %.data) nounwind {
 enrty:
 ....
 }
```

Can someone please suggest a method for this function insertion?

Answer (score 2):

Use the LLVM `cpp` backend to get an answer to this and any other similar question.

Also, there is online [demo page](http://llvm.org/demo/), which can emit C++ code for given source.

Comment: the demo page c++ backend is severely outdated, and renders code that won't work in recent versions of LLVM (3.0)